# Getting symbol names into C

Tags: c, assembly, automation, macros, linker

I have successfully produced an assembler macro which I use to instantiate 32 *independent* routines in a assembly source file. The routines follow the target system ABI. Their exported symbol names are all practically identical, except for a trailing number suffix. Here is an symbol extract from the assembled object file (ellipsis indicating continuing pattern).

```
$ nm default_handler.o | sort
...
00000058 T exception_default_handler_5
0000005f T exception_default_handler_6
00000066 T exception_default_handler_7
0000006d T exception_default_handler_8
00000072 T exception_default_handler_9
00000079 T exception_default_handler_10
0000007e T exception_default_handler_11
00000083 T exception_default_handler_12
00000088 T exception_default_handler_13
...
```

I also have a C program in which I need to reference each of these individual routines. In some parts of the C program, I need to reference all of the assembly routines at once, to store a pointer of each in an array. Here is the necessary code needed to understand my problem (with ellipsis to indicate a continuing pattern). This code preforms the task stated above.

```
{
    ...
    extern void exception_default_handler_5(void);
    extern void exception_default_handler_6(void);
    extern void exception_default_handler_7(void);
    ...

    ...
    array[5] = exception_default_handler_5;
    array[6] = exception_default_handler_6;
    array[7] = exception_default_handler_7;
    ...
}
```

With 64 lines of this approach; the *coding golden rule*, to always write readable and maintainable code, have obviously been broken. What I would like is a way to automize this process of making an extern forward declaration and putting an instance of it in the array, to minimize the errors that are bound to happen when code is duplicated.

I am thinking that perhaps it's a job for the C-macros, but I cannot figure out a way to do it with them.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Even if you come up with some preprocessor magic to solve it, it will break half a dozen other *golden rules*. Use script if you must.